# Windows key is acting wierd

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-key

My keyboard used to work fine, but recently (no idea exactly when) my windows key has started acting weird.

When I press and hold the windows key it activates the start menu, even without letting go. This is preventing me from doing any shortcuts involving the windows key, since it just opens the start menu. It appears that the start menu is activated by the down-press of the windows key, and when it activates the windows key is considered released.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: See if the keycap is removable, if it is, remove it and clean it, there might be some foreign object there, causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably needs cleaning or the switch needs replacing.

If its the usual cheap keyboard it will be cheapest to simply replace the whole thing.

If in doubt, connect a different keyboard and see if the same problem persists.

Comment: Lol, now i feel bad for asking the question. Should I just remove it?
BTW, it worked

Comment: No need to delete the question -- it can still be useful for others. If RedGrittyBrick's answer solved your problem, you should consider marking it as the [Accepted Answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer), using the checkmark to the left of the question.